universal property of topological subspace
Reading Lee "Introduction to topological manifolds", I encountered the following property of topological subspaces:

(Characteristic Property of the Subspace Topology). Suppose $X$
is a topological space and $S \subseteq X$ is a subspace. For any topological space $Y$, a
map $f: Y\rightarrow S$ is continuous if and only if the composite map $i_s\circ f: Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous:$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
{} & {} & X \\
{} & \overset{i_S \circ f}{\nearrow} & \uparrow i_S \\
Y & \underset{f}{\to} & S
\end{array}
$$

In the proof of this proposition, it was used that if there is an open subset $U$ in $S$, then there exists open $V\subseteq X$ such that $U=V\cap S= i_S^{-1}(V)$. But I didn't really get how can we take preimage of $V$ which is not entirely in $S$? I mean, $i_S$ image is $S$, which in general lies strictly in $X$, so how can we take preimage of points which are not in the image?
From which rises the question, why do we need to consider the whole $X$ in this proposition, since we only deal with the subset of $X$?

Preimages are defined for any subset of the codomain.  Has nothing to do with the image.

You should look up the definition of preimage. I don't understand the second question: The property you're trying to prove is a statement about $X$ (among other things), and how maps into a subspace of $X$ relate to maps into $X$ itself. If you cut out $X$ there is no proposition to prove.

There are two different concepts with the same notation:

For a mapping $f:A\rightarrow B$ and a subset $E$ of $B$, the subset $f^{-1}(E)$ of $A$ is defined as the set of all $a\in A$ with $f(a)\in E$. This does not need any further assumption on $f$ or $E$.

If $f$ is bijective, we can speak of the function $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$. If $E$ is a subset of $B$, $f^{-1}(E)$ is the image of $E$ under $f^{-1}$.


Note that, if the condition of 2. is satisfied and we read $f^{-1}(E)$, we don't need to think about whether this is meant in the sense of 1. or 2., because both definitions result in the same set.
In your case, $i_S$ is not bijective. Since $V$ is not necessarily a subset of $i_S(S)$, it is clear that the definition 1. is meant.

Thank you for the answer! It seems like I've messed with the concepts and notations of inverse map and preimage, and your notes clarified it.

As pointed out in the comment the preimages does not bring with it definitional problems. What I mean is that the immersion $i:S\to X$ is a well defined application so take $V\subseteq X$ there are two possibilities
$$S\cap V= \emptyset, \qquad S\cap V \neq \emptyset$$
In the first case
$$i^{-1}_S(V) = \emptyset$$
(I'd like to point out that is still an open preimage!) In the second case
$$i^{-1}_S(V) =\{s\in S : i(s) \in V\}$$
And you have a well defined set of elements in $S$. Don't bother yourself with elements that are in $V \backslash S$ since for those elements simply $i^{-1}_S(v) = \emptyset$.

Hope this can help!
